# Init object error TypeError: 'int' objecthas no attribute, python with generator

Tags: python, types, generator, pool

I have a fucntion like:

`def image_process(ind):
    return rotate(img[ind])`

I am calling this function with `Pool.imap` to construct a generator
something like:

`gen= pool.imap(image_process,[1,2,3,4,5,6],chunksize=100)`

However, this generator seems to be empty. I can't run a forloop over it. 
As soon as the interpreter reaches the following line:
`for k,im in enumerate(gen)` it throws an error: TypeError 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: inside `image_process`, are you sure that `img` is something that isn't an `int`?

Comment: The traceback/exception should tell you the line that is failing.

Comment: problem was solved but I have no clue what caused it. in my function image_process(), there is a list called `img`. This list has been defined and initialized in top of the module so, I assumed it can be seen by my function. But somehow when using pool.imap, it can't see it and I have to pass it as an argument to it. Any explanation would be appreciated